# Advanced search box in document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, advanced-search

I have a **document library** and it saves a lot of **document set**. The **document set** have different **field** like name, age or subject. My question is how can I use **advanced search box** in **document library** and only show the **document set** after search?

I am a beginner so please tell me more detail. I don't even know the xml code in **properties**. One more thing, the advanced search box must do the condition like  Equal, Less and Greater Than.